# SwiftUI multi line text throws error in canvas simulator

Tags: swift, text, swiftui

I'm reaching out for you because after hours of trying I'm not able to find the solution for my problem.

In a ZStack I'm using `Text()` to position a text snippet I'm reading from a JSON-File on an image. So far so good. The text snippets contain newlines `\n`, that's why I wanted to use multi line literals (`"""`). When using plain text, that's none of a problem, but when I start using the text I get from my JSON-File the canvas simulator gives the following error:

```
Compiling failed: Multi-line string literal content must begin on a new line
```

When building the App on my iPhone, there is now error, but the `\n` do not lead to line breaks.

This is my code:

```
Text("""
      \(card.card_text)
     """)
```

When trying this

```
Text("""
      hello\ndarkness\nmy\nold\nfriend
     """)
```

everything is working as expected.

This is an example for `card.card_text`:

`"card_text": "Take one Card\\nGive two cards two the player on your right\nYou cannot use a money card in the next round"`

Could somebody please push me into the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need multiline literals (it's for literals!), `Text` handles newlines perfectly as is

so this

```
Text("Take one Card\nGive two cards two the player on your right\nYou cannot use a money card in the next round")
```

gives

[image: demo]

so just check if your JSON has correct string (eg: you have `Card\\nGive` - double slash)

Comment: Thank you so much! Feeling reeeaaaally stupid right now :D. I really didn't notice that I was using \\n and not \n